# General questions about Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in R

Tags: r, pca

I would like to produce some nice PCA plots in R. As usual, in R, there are several ways to perform a principal component analysis. I found so far 3 different ways of how to calculate your components and 3 ways of plotting them. I was wondering whether people who are familiar with these functions can give me some advise on the best combination of functions to produce the following plots:

- Scores Plot
- Loadings Plot
- Histogram / Bar chart of the variances explained by each principal component

My research on functions and plots used for PCA in R resulted in:

Functions:

- pca.xzy()
- prcomp()
- princomp()
- dudi.pca()

Plot:

- plot.pca (this one seems to belong to the function pca.xzy())
- ggplot2
- plot
- biplot

I also found the following webpage:

http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ade4/ade4-html/dudi.pca.html

And I was wondering if you can draw those circles and lines starting from each of the circle centers with one of the other functions mentioned above as the function dudi.pca from the ade4 package seems to be the most complicated one.

Comment: Don't forget FactorMineR, here's a worked example with the circles and lines you mention: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10253792/1036500

Answer (score 2):

One question per question, please! There's `psych` package by William Revelle, see [this](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html) and [this](http://www.personality-project.org/r/r.guide.html#factoranal). There's also a good tutorial [here](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2010/05/tutorial-principle-components-analysis.html). Anyway...

- for scores/loadings plot see `pairs`
- histogram: see `hist`

So once again, what's your question actually? =)