# PCA in R: prcomp and confidence ellipses

Tags: r, pca

I recently ran PCA with the prcomp() function in R, and now I would need to (objectively) decide which samples from my two different groups are outliers and should be removed from further analyses.

I have previously seen PCA plots where confidence/variance ellipses (not sure about the terminology) are put around samples, leaving outside the ones that are considered outliers (e.g. let's say something like more than 3 standard deviations away from the cluster centroid). How would I achieve something like this in R?

Note: I looked a bit at the ["car" package](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/car/html/Ellipses.html), but it is still not clear how the data.ellipse would be used for the PC1 vs PC2 projection plot, for example. Any help/relevant resources are appreciated!

Thank you!

Edit: The R object I am using and one of the plots that I would like to use for outlier marking:

```
countsTable <- read.table('sample.txt', header=T)
transpose.counts.table <- t(countsTable)
input.for.pca <- transpose.counts.table[, colSums(abs(transpose.counts.table)) != 0]
my.prc <- prcomp(input.for.pca, center=T, scale=T)

pdf("PCA_Results_PC1_PC2_prcomp_counts.pdf")
plot(my.prc$x[,1], my.prc$x[,2], type='p', cex=0.0, pch=20, main="PCA: Samples' projection on PC1 and PC2 (raw counts)", xlab="PC1", ylab="PC2")
text(my.prc$x[,1], my.prc$x[,2], labels=rownames(my.prc$x), cex=1.2)
dev.off()
```

Updated input.for.pca object, which contains a categorical "type" column:

```
> dput(input.for.pca)
structure(list(A1BG = c(190L, 125L, 95L, 115L, 483L, 94L, 87L, 
211L, 153L, 135L, 116L, 110L, 75L, 159L, 148L, 159L, 177L, 103L, 
103L, 88L, 112L, 87L, 272L, 100L, 313L, 169L, 130L, 164L, 114L, 
154L, 168L, 197L, 125L, 95L, 118L, 154L, 197L, 203L, 184L, 86L, 
142L, 111L, 140L, 63L), A1BG.AS1 = c(77L, 94L, 53L, 52L, 56L, 
67L, 55L, 112L, 95L, 51L, 28L, 50L, 35L, 87L, 44L, 93L, 44L, 
16L, 21L, 24L, 42L, 43L, 159L, 59L, 125L, 108L, 50L, 68L, 55L, 
81L, 81L, 39L, 64L, 67L, 66L, 57L, 114L, 82L, 51L, 21L, 126L, 
24L, 53L, 3L), A1CF = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 15L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 0L), A2LD1 = c(94L, 51L, 52L, 57L, 64L, 40L, 48L, 61L, 
83L, 53L, 49L, 31L, 40L, 66L, 50L, 43L, 54L, 14L, 73L, 58L, 50L, 
36L, 132L, 88L, 96L, 73L, 47L, 73L, 100L, 49L, 40L, 54L, 34L, 
34L, 45L, 56L, 77L, 66L, 90L, 62L, 67L, 47L, 80L, 9L), A2M = c(4407L, 
4755L, 1739L, 2049L, 3219L, 2598L, 2531L, 3894L, 2067L, 2703L, 
3776L, 774L, 3129L, 2924L, 1997L, 5803L, 3147L, 5472L, 9608L, 
3315L, 6164L, 1250L, 5911L, 4688L, 2775L, 4561L, 7165L, 3605L, 
8228L, 4835L, 7124L, 4689L, 5306L, 3643L, 3190L, 3290L, 4932L, 
1990L, 9610L, 7476L, 4533L, 4035L, 3275L, 1326L), A2ML1 = c(195L, 
207L, 63L, 291L, 24L, 126L, 168L, 251L, 39L, 145L, 213L, 126L, 
179L, 169L, 141L, 272L, 185L, 115L, 588L, 156L, 111L, 45L, 301L, 
182L, 155L, 146L, 91L, 160L, 155L, 73L, 44L, 103L, 182L, 71L, 
164L, 405L, 245L, 165L, 162L, 317L, 188L, 153L, 228L, 11L), A4GALT = c(191L, 
86L, 64L, 200L, 39L, 118L, 106L, 64L, 11L, 40L, 144L, 53L, 134L, 
101L, 138L, 138L, 214L, 138L, 406L, 145L, 497L, 72L, 473L, 86L, 
41L, 213L, 172L, 77L, 657L, 73L, 123L, 126L, 106L, 44L, 125L, 
106L, 56L, 114L, 756L, 328L, 151L, 210L, 213L, 42L), A4GNT = c(3L, 
3L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), AA06 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AAA1 = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L), AAAS = c(829L, 1042L, 
844L, 805L, 1700L, 953L, 809L, 1052L, 1266L, 781L, 618L, 929L, 
699L, 992L, 1001L, 1423L, 845L, 1054L, 808L, 711L, 938L, 756L, 
1384L, 944L, 1689L, 1052L, 703L, 890L, 1293L, 727L, 804L, 1227L, 
668L, 794L, 835L, 877L, 1514L, 1287L, 1435L, 941L, 1115L, 868L, 
923L, 288L), AACS = c(2350L, 1953L, 1884L, 1702L, 421L, 1530L, 
1435L, 3619L, 815L, 1320L, 859L, 1708L, 1096L, 2124L, 1029L, 
1930L, 1241L, 724L, 867L, 893L, 1797L, 447L, 4854L, 1670L, 2675L, 
2471L, 1874L, 1620L, 2515L, 3156L, 2079L, 1345L, 1684L, 1615L, 
1650L, 1386L, 3470L, 1958L, 2278L, 1076L, 3459L, 1115L, 1369L, 
121L), AACSP1 = c(19L, 6L, 11L, 13L, 1L, 11L, 13L, 27L, 5L, 12L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 18L, 17L, 0L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 19L, 16L, 30L, 
11L, 12L, 20L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 16L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 
5L, 18L, 6L, 5L, 0L), AADAC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), AADACL2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AADACL3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AADACL4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), AADAT = c(387L, 416L, 297L, 392L, 682L, 422L, 
287L, 704L, 50L, 373L, 306L, 234L, 225L, 340L, 220L, 443L, 387L, 
324L, 304L, 261L, 259L, 181L, 801L, 428L, 925L, 498L, 270L, 524L, 
654L, 472L, 334L, 395L, 414L, 440L, 318L, 306L, 645L, 418L, 350L, 
277L, 468L, 302L, 298L, 48L), AAGAB = c(1235L, 1231L, 1026L, 
981L, 477L, 877L, 808L, 2217L, 764L, 914L, 670L, 974L, 538L, 
1362L, 492L, 1078L, 764L, 297L, 582L, 615L, 923L, 307L, 3055L, 
1195L, 1673L, 1673L, 1070L, 1052L, 1761L, 2198L, 1221L, 813L, 
1050L, 997L, 865L, 930L, 2065L, 1190L, 1243L, 578L, 1931L, 664L, 
874L, 75L), AAK1 = c(6457L, 6538L, 4706L, 4917L, 1252L, 4055L, 
4063L, 11627L, 9127L, 3604L, 2439L, 4221L, 3968L, 5065L, 2450L, 
5690L, 3065L, 1082L, 2756L, 2886L, 3763L, 1360L, 15237L, 4771L, 
7881L, 8349L, 5177L, 4888L, 6532L, 7856L, 5373L, 3487L, 4885L, 
4461L, 3893L, 4152L, 9055L, 4656L, 4501L, 2598L, 8079L, 3187L, 
3655L, 337L), AAMP = c(2282L, 2585L, 2113L, 2197L, 2226L, 1776L, 
2097L, 3614L, 2494L, 2215L, 1707L, 2109L, 1740L, 2620L, 1703L, 
2357L, 1965L, 1697L, 1724L, 1623L, 2299L, 1109L, 5555L, 2550L, 
4239L, 3149L, 2127L, 2487L, 3966L, 2817L, 2043L, 1967L, 2092L, 
2031L, 2123L, 2661L, 4203L, 2884L, 3224L, 1678L, 3876L, 1963L, 
2362L, 473L), AANAT = c(33L, 51L, 14L, 26L, 23L, 12L, 36L, 14L, 
27L, 24L, 30L, 17L, 11L, 45L, 31L, 28L, 23L, 67L, 77L, 26L, 44L, 
17L, 86L, 70L, 16L, 39L, 10L, 27L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 10L, 12L, 
18L, 28L, 41L, 40L, 85L, 40L, 48L, 30L, 46L, 8L), AARS = c(6383L, 
9377L, 6772L, 8134L, 5605L, 4734L, 5902L, 13757L, 6832L, 6566L, 
4009L, 5377L, 7209L, 7749L, 4105L, 6969L, 5120L, 5484L, 5486L, 
4935L, 6604L, 3151L, 24172L, 7615L, 12786L, 12676L, 7009L, 8208L, 
11328L, 11550L, 7054L, 4789L, 6547L, 6686L, 6109L, 6456L, 14576L, 
8317L, 8057L, 4626L, 13162L, 5801L, 6090L, 1498L), AARS2 = c(1032L, 
858L, 687L, 735L, 527L, 655L, 641L, 1480L, 1713L, 753L, 561L, 
541L, 459L, 819L, 462L, 867L, 605L, 404L, 571L, 497L, 637L, 343L, 
1761L, 1082L, 1379L, 815L, 841L, 844L, 1150L, 1121L, 973L, 665L, 
696L, 672L, 824L, 511L, 1313L, 861L, 998L, 626L, 1258L, 555L, 
623L, 115L), AARSD1 = c(918L, 1218L, 793L, 877L, 573L, 867L, 
916L, 2030L, 1198L, 1015L, 715L, 909L, 437L, 1245L, 566L, 1083L, 
985L, 325L, 584L, 621L, 871L, 353L, 2033L, 887L, 1412L, 1205L, 
1143L, 1037L, 1592L, 1413L, 1183L, 1216L, 1121L, 888L, 1021L, 
846L, 2189L, 1182L, 1412L, 656L, 1708L, 797L, 988L, 80L), type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("control", 
"diseased"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A1BG", "A1BG.AS1", 
"A1CF", "A2LD1", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A4GALT", "A4GNT", "AA06", "AAA1", 
"AAAS", "AACS", "AACSP1", "AADAC", "AADACL2", "AADACL3", "AADACL4", 
"AADAT", "AAGAB", "AAK1", "AAMP", "AANAT", "AARS", "AARS2", "AARSD1", 
"type"), row.names = c("C_2", "C_4", "C_6", "C_8", "C_9", "C_10", 
"C_14", "C_15", "C_18", "C_21", "C_29", "P_3", "P_6", "P_13", 
"P_15", "P_18", "P_19", "P_21", "P_22", "P_29", "P_31", "C_3", 
"C_5", "C_11", "C_12", "C_13", "C_16", "C_17", "C_19", "C_20", 
"C_22", "C_23", "C_24", "C_25", "C_26", "P_14", "P_16", "P_20", 
"P_23", "P_26", "P_27", "P_28", "P_30", "P_33"), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks to DWin's input, I looked into the FactoMineR package, which was able to plot the type of confidence ellipses that I was asking about. This is the used code:

```
res.pca <- PCA(input.for.pca, scale.unit=T, ncp=5, quali.sup = 26, graph = F)
concat = cbind.data.frame(input.for.pca[,26], res.pca$ind$coord)
ellipse.coord = coord.ellipse(concat, level.conf = 0.99999, bary=T)
plot.PCA(res.pca, ellipse = ellipse.coord, axes=c(1, 2), choix="ind", habillage=26)
```

You might notice the level.conf option for the coord.ellipse function. By changing this option from the default 0.95, I was able to increase the size of the ellipses.

I found [this link](http://factominer.free.fr/classical-methods/principal-components-analysis.html) useful for understanding how to work with FactoMineR.

Comment: Show how to construct or provide an R data object.

Comment: Answers to this question on plotting confidence ellipses in ggplot2 may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397097/how-can-a-data-ellipse-be-superimposed-on-a-ggplot2-scatterplot

Comment: `read.table(rna.seq.input.file, header=T)` is NOT reproducible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936051/adding-ellipses-to-a-principal-component-analysis-pca-plot

Comment: @DWin: I am not sure what the best way to adding data to a post is. I tried pasting in the beginning of my 'rna.seq.input.file' file. Would this suffice? When plotting the result from the my.prc object, points C_9, C_15, and C_18 are outliers.

Comment: The best way would have been to included the output of `dput()` on that sample data. Then people would not have to go through the error prone process of inputting it with `read.table` and not know what the exact structure was.

Comment: Thank you, DWin, I did not know about this function.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, Alexandra. You obviously saw that nomination for duplicate question from Ben. It supports the notion that you need to have a grouping variable and your data has none as of the present.

Comment: I added a grouping variable while playing with FactoMineR today. While I got some confidence ellipses displayed (the plotellipses function), they are not the ellipses I am interested in - I was unable to change the ellipses with the level option for plotellipses. I will update my posting soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of data to work with, I can suggest looking at the FactoMineR package which prmises some sort of PCA plot with optional ellipses: plot.PCA   "Draw the Principal Component Analysis (PCA) graphs:. Setting the 'ellipse' argument to a non NULL value is supposed to : " draw ellipses around the individuals, and use the results of `coord.ellipse`".

Working with your data using `FactoMiner::PCA` I am able to get the same sort of plot as results from your `prcomp` call.

```
require(FactoMineR)
PCAres <-PCA(input.for.pca)  # draws two plots as a side-effect
```

I'm not able to get data-ellipses using its inbuilt argument in the plotting routine. Examining the example for that routine on its help page I believe it is due to the fact that it needs a factor category identifier to mark membership in groups so that the component values can be label and ellipses drawn around the group centroids.

Comment: For whomever is interested, please see the working code at the end of my question.