# R FactoMineR Package: level.conf option of the coord.ellipse function

Tags: r, pca, confidence-interval

I had a [question answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269435/pca-in-r-prcomp-and-confidence-ellipses) about drawing confidence ellipses for PCA (principal components analyses) plots.

What ended up working was the FactoMineR package (a combination of the PCA, coord.ellipse, and plot.PCA functions). While I can draw now confidence ellipses, I do not understand what the level.conf option of the coord.ellipse function actually does. I was expecting smaller ellipses with increased confidence levels, but the opposite is happening.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a higher degree of confidence that your ellipses includes the "true" value (in the case of parameter estimation) or that it includes a higher proportion of the population (in the case of prediction ellipses) then you use a higher confidence figure. This principle applies very widely. Higher degrees of confidence require wider intervals to meet the demands you are specifying.

Comment: Thank you so much! I might be done with the questions for the day :).