# coloring PCA plots by factor in R

Tags: r, pca

I have been doing PCA in R using the pcaMethods package. I am having some difficulty with coloring my points by factor when plotting.

```
labels <- read.table("example", header=TRUE, sep=",")
groupings <- factor(labels$type)
plotPcs(pcResults, col=groupings)
```

the file "example" would look like this:

```
no, type
1, carrot
2, carrot
3, turnip
4, turnip
5, brussel
```

It does what I want if the number of factors are limited, however, when I have a lot of factors there does not appear to be enough default colors and some factors get plotted with the same color. What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: This question has been asked a few times already. Here is one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286858/plotting-pca-scores-with-color

Comment: I can plot the PCA and color the points by factor. My problem is when the number of factors exceeds the default colors. Is there anyway of specifying a new default color palette with a much larger array of colors?

Comment: have a look at the `RColorBrewer` and `colorspace` package. Though qualitative palettes have a somewhat natural upper limit for different colors. You could use e.g. `rainbow_hcl` from the latter. Example: `plot(1:20, col=rainbow_hcl(20), pch=16, cex=2)`