# show.groups argument in ordiellipse() to use different colours and line types for groups

Tags: plot, colors, ellipse, vegan

I am trying to produce a plot like the one shown at the bottom of this question: [Adding ellipses to a principal component analysis (PCA) plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936051/adding-ellipses-to-a-principal-component-analysis-pca-plot/14251240#14251240).
However, I am neither familiar with `ggplot` nor with modifying the function `ordiellipse()` itself like shown here: [Color-coding 95% confidence ellipses for centroids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936051/adding-ellipses-to-a-principal-component-analysis-pca-plot/14251240#14251240).

Therefore, I tried using the argument `show.groups` in `ordiellipse()` but I cannot figure out how to tell this argument what I want.

I am analyzing a table with 83 sites that contains abundance data for about 418 species.
I run a DCA with the function `decorana()` and downweighted rare species on the data. Afterwards I am fitting mean Ellenberg indicator values onto the ordination.

```
vali <-read.table(file = "VegOrdi2012.txt", header=T)
attach(vali)

calcul.env<-read.table(file = "indicator-values-2012.txt",header=T)
attach(calcul.env)
names(calcul.env)

#Downweighting of rare species
calcul.dca1<-decorana(vali,iweigh=1)
calcul.dca1

#Fitting of environmental values
habi<-envfit(calcul.dca1~Habitat+Light+Temp+Continent+Moisture+pH+Nutrients+Salt,calcul.env,permu=999)
habi
```

It is the factor `Habitat` that I need to visualize in a diagram by means of `ordiellipse()` together with all the 83 plots shown as points and their plot number as text. Habitat consists of nine categories which comprise:

```
with(calcul.env, levels(Habitat))
[1] "Brown"  "Emb"    "Eph"    "FBS"    "GreeS"  "RiBa"   "Tracks" "TraffA"
[9] "UrbanL"
```

I was able to color and label them without drawing ellipses around them:

```
#Assigning colors to the nine categories
colvec <- c("black", "darkviolet", "green3", "darkorange", "magenta", "deepskyblue", "red", "blue", "forestgreen")

plot(calcul.dca1, type = "n", xlim=c(-1.5,1.6),ylim=c(-3,3))
ordipointlabel(calcul.dca1, display="site", cex=0.7, col = colvec[Habitat],bg = colvec[Habitat],pch = 21)

# Creating a legend
with(calcul.env, legend("topright", legend = levels(Habitat), cex=0.65,bty = "n",col = colvec, pch = 21, pt.bg = colvec))
```

But how do I tell the `show.groups` argument how to color the different `Habitat` types as well as assigning a different line type other than the standard one to the nine ellipses?

So far, I came up with this plot by using:

```
plot(calcul.dca, type="n", xlim=c(-1.5,1.6),ylim=c(-1,1))

ordiellipse(calcul.dca, Habitat, display="site", kind = "sd",
conf = 0.95, label = T, col="black", cex=0.7)
```

But it is rather elusive as it only shows the ellipses without the plots even though I added `display="site"`. Also, because they're heavily overlapping it is hard to see which one is which. Therefore, it would be great to color each habitat type differently.

In case you need an extract of my DCA ordination data, here it comes:

```
dput(calcul.dca1)

structure(list(rproj = structure(c(0.622196100508291, 0.0425187062298239, 
0.809118643435233, 1.42649346881288, 0.942469303820393, 2.14549756552088, 
2.41922446503012, 1.28982244065239, 2.38544988614361, 1.40637644094225, 
1.91277135864581, 0.605410167146248, 0.806888393988314, 0.683853698855826, 
0.487565297706596, 1.33517822183407, 1.0239859712969, 1.11996240234112, 
0.878649568698446, 1.53912253203697, 1.10967929396299, 1.23838793138041, 
0.423890604035373, 0.624635178433215, 0.625774941613906, 0.873372685928585, 
1.02496140772642, 1.44785313041614, 1.08257665268759, 0.349688854561329, 
0.391547839427374, 0.730346245879122, 0.286646737460428, 0.731484625760109, 
1.08559070145785, 1.53243971551768, 0.85664914035342, 1.81525177285522, 
1.5519555131377, 1.39064843441504, 0.760013397658093, 1.22801365648165, 
2.21178067417998, 1.79390604164473, 1.65361126768449, 1.73966835197937, 
1.9237320812287, 1.80114956024378, 2.23293893445506, 2.02322760613128, 
...
0.857428410615221, 1.48594779863814, 0.935954361867925, 1.0524685508641, 
0.898391402052793), .Dim = c(84L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("p1", 
"p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", 
"p12", "p13", "p14", "p15", "p16", "p17", "p18", "p19", "p20", 
"p21", "p22", "p23", "p24", "p25", "p26", "p27", "p28", "p29", 
"p30", "p31", "p32", "p33", "p34", "p35", "p36", "p37", "p38", 
"p39", "p40", "p41", "p42", "p43", "p44", "p45", "p46", "p47", 
"p48", "p49", "p50", "p51", "p52", "p53", "p54", "p55", "p56", 
"p57", "p58", "p59", "p61", "p62", "p63", "p64", "p65", "p66", 
"p67", "p68", "p69", "p70", "p71", "p73", "p74", "p75", "p76", 
"p77", "p78", "p79", "p80", "p81", "p82", "p83", "p85", "p86", 
"p87"), c("DCA1", "DCA2", "DCA3", "DCA4"))), cproj = structure(c(1.25651540418674, 
4.10086480672813, 0.985170303000948, 0.356752380731314, 0.0871005927968299, 
-0.65389620717045, 0.416500256857967, -0.0687562150601063, -0.448057138258203, 
-0.851379298478351, -4.22395990436862, 3.38456796429771, 3.50656010401288, 
3.0970679364606, 3.76068022295243, 4.15832492473722, 1.73508588573266, 
-0.0979648246992866, -1.54594775838685, 0.0871005366833882, 2.10389514743405, 
0.705016209734685, -1.54594765746973, -0.264737082168187, 1.28992362813467, 
...
2.37831113227017, 2.6918186855265, 3.96654774047496), .Dim = c(414L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Ace_cam", "Ace_pla", "Ace_pse", "Ach_mil", 
"Aeg_pod", "Aes_hip", "Agr_cap", "Agr_sto", "All_pet", "Alo_pra", 
"Alo_myo", "Ama_alb", "Ama_bli", "Ama_pow", "Ama_ret", "Amb_art", 
"Ame_lam", "Ang_arc", "Anc_arv", "Ant_cau", "Ant_syl", "Ant_tin", 
"Ant_vul", "Ape_spi", "Aqu_vul", "Ara_tha", "Arc_lap", "Arc_min", 
"Are_ser", "Arr_ela", "Art_bie", "Art_cam", "Art_vul", "Asp_rut", 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding each ellipse separately and assign the colors from colvec to each Habitat group separately using `show.groups`.  For example:

```
with(calcul.env, ordiellipse(calcul.dca, Habitat, kind="se", conf=0.95,
                       lwd=2, col="black", show.groups = "Brown"))
with(calcul.env, ordiellipse(calcul.dca, Habitat, kind="se", conf=0.95,
                       lwd=2, col="darkviolet", show.groups = "Emb"))
with(calcul.env, ordiellipse(calcul.dca, Habitat, kind="se", conf=0.95,
                       lwd=2, col="green3", show.groups = "Eph"))
```

and so forth.  You can make this easier by creating a loop if you want.  See http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg149786.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for! It is working perfectly except for two categories which only contain one site. Also, it looks like the ellipses are drawn mirror-inverted because the respective sites are located on the other side of the diagram. But this happens regardless of the coloring. Is this a statistical problem? Should I discuss this over at http://stats.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but a mirror image of an ordination would still show the same relationships between sites.