# Color PCA depending on predefined groups?

Tags: r, pca

I have a problem, when i try to do a PCA plot on some gene expression data, i use the code below to plot it, but i would like to make different colors depending on which category a Tissue belongs to.

```
data <- read.table("rmaFinal.txt", row.names=1, sep="\t",header=TRUE, dec=".")
pca <- prcomp(t(data), cor=TRUE)
plot(pca$x, pch=20)
```

My data is formatted as

```
      Tissue1 tissue2 tissue3
Gene1 1        2       3
Gene2 2        3       4
Gene3 3        4       5
```

I have a total of 116 different tissues, that all can be classified into a total of 12 categories. I therefore have a list like this, with the category of each of the 116 tissue types.

```
category = c( "Seed","Seed","Seed","Stem","Seed","Seed","Seed","Mesocotyl","Spikelets")
```

I would like to color my PCA plot depending on which of the 12 categories a given sample is present in. 
I have tried to read around, but none of the solutions i could find did work for this.
How do i combine the category list with the PCA plot?

Comment: and a duplicate of this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13936051/1036500

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```
library(FactoMineR)
iris.pca <- PCA(iris, quali.sup=5)
plot(iris.pca, habillage = 5, 
     col.hab = c("green", "blue", "red"), 
     title = "Dataset projected onto PC1-2 Subspace")
```

[image]

hat-tip: http://benmabey.com/presentations/pca-tutorial/#34

Comment: Hi Ben, yes it is, but if i don't want to include the categories in the same matrix, is it then possible to have it as a vector like i have put above? and how do i handle that with the quali_sup?

Comment: Probably best if you asked another question showing what you've tried among these lines. I'll keep my eye out for it!

Comment: Yes, sorry, have been on holidays without internet. I ended up using the ggplot library.  
    type=c("Seed","Seed","Seed","Stem"... )
    qplot(pca$x[,1],pca$x[,2], colour=type, xlab="PCA 1", ylab="PCA 2")
No idea why it doesn't mark it as code, sorry.
Thanks for the help